C# How to overcome Interface Nullability for getters
Given:
//Common interface for objects that may have an Id value
interface IMaybeHasId
{
    int? Id { get; }  //Note this is a GET only
}

//Object A never has an Id, this code works fine
class ObjectA : IMaybeHasId
{
    public int? Id => null;
}

//Object B always has an Id
//This code will not work as Id here is Int not Int?
class ObjectB : IMaybeHasId
{
    public int Id => 10;
}

I need this because when my code works with a pure reference to Object B The code can expect that Id is always available.
When working with a pure reference to Object A, the Id may not be available.
But I want to place them into a common collection ie List()
When working with the items in the list its ok to worry about Id possible being null as per the interface. Ie we would have an object reference via the interface contract where Id is Int?  Totally fine.
The compiler will stop the above code from compiling
This is a real pain as from a human perspective there is no real issue here.
The contract of Object B (Always having an Id) would comply with the interface that the object type May have an Id.  Note this contract is a GET so having a non null value fits into a nullable restriction. It just happens to never be null.
Obviously this would not be work if the property was writable / setter. Because object B would not be able to accept null values.  But in this case we are readonly so it 'could' work.
If anyone has a nice way to solve this issue then please let me know.

Sounds like you need IHasId and Class ObjectA does not implement it. Then to check it you can do (someObj as IHasId)?.Id

Please post real code when you ask a question.

You need to implement the interface explicitly. Then you can easily keep the public int Id => 10; yet still implement the interface.
class ObjectB : IMaybeHasId
{
    public int Id => 10;
    int? IMaybeHasId.Id => this.Id;
}


Extending on top of @Enigmativity's great answer, I propose:
interface IMaybeHasId
{
    int? Id { get; }
}

interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; } 
}

class ObjectB : IMaybeHasId, IHasId
{
    public int Id => 10; // this will implement IHasId
    int? IMaybeHasId.Id => this.Id; // this will implement IMaybeHasId
}

This way if you had ObjectC that is similar to ObjectB the similarity (that you want to make it easy to access the raw int) is made clear through IHasId.

You could add a NotNull attribute to ObjectB's Id property.
class ObjectB : IMaybeHasId
{
    [NotNull]
    public int? Id => 10;
}

This at least lets the IDE now this value will never be null. If you would check this property for null in your code, you would get a type hint telling you the check is redundant because it will never be null.
However, you can not change the actual type of the property. How about adding a new property to ObjectB, public int RequiredId { get; } that uses the IMaybeHasId.Id property behind the scenes?

Did you test this before posting?
